# Windows 7 - KB976932 - Installation fails with error 800b0100

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I am having an issue with Windows 7 Update (`KB976932`). it continues to fail with the error `800b0100`

I have tried several articles on the internet to find help.. but nothing works.

Anyone knows how to get it through (without reinstallation of windows)

Thanks

Comment: Is it only this update that fails or do others fail as well? How do you try to install it? Through Windows update, or using the KB976932 installer directly?

Comment: Have you tried the System Update Readiness tool yet? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-800b0100#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @LPChip
Its the only one that fails... I have re-tried it many many times from `updates` window

Comment: @Tyler these guides on the windows website doesnt show how to actually run "System Update Readiness" tool. They just talk about how to install it.

Comment: @RaheelHasan Right, all you need to do is install it and then try running Windows Update again. Trying to narrow down what you have/have not tried so far.

Comment: @Tyler well, I already have done that.. that didnt work...

Answer (score 1):

Use *SFC* (and *DISM* on Win  8) to remove any incomplete updates, then the *System Update Readiness* tool again. See the following for bothe Windows 7 and 8 techniques:

[Error 0x800B0100 when you try to install Windows Updates or Microsoft Updates](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/956702)  and  [Windows Update error 0x80070490](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958044) (yes, it is a different error number, but the fixes apply to both issues, specifically using SFC and DISM for Win 8, which back out some of the updates that had been partially installed).

It may then require going through the normal Windows Update process multiple times but should resolve the issue.

Please let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok will try it and let you know if it works...

Comment: nops that didnt work.. The `Fix It` couldnt fix it, and the `sfc /scannow` says `Windows Resource Protection found c
em.
Details are included in the CBS.Log
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`

Comment: but this is a fresh installation of windows... how did it corrupt?!!